# Is there a way to make a URL to search without specifying the website?

Tags: url, search, permalinks

I would like to make a URL that searches without specifying which site to use.
Ideally it would search using the default search engine as commonly implemented in the address bar of web browsers.
Is there a protocol or anything similar for this and if not why and if there are any future possibilities?

*The reason for this is to create long lasting URLs with search data that do no rely on say a company like Google.

Comment: Is "No" an acceptable answer?

Comment: It seems like "No" is the answer, but I am puzzled as to why such a useful function has not been standardized or at least discussed.
Where I live(Japan), AR codes are the standard everywhere but they use Google urls when doing a search term. The main reason I would want this is to provide decentralized links to data made possible through specifying theoretically enough information to make it unique. All that would be needed is something like search:timestamp=...&location=...&info=...

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to host your own server, you could write a simple Flask app to accept a search term as a parameter and loop over possible search engines to use so there is always a fallback. The drawback here is that you'd have to continuously make adjustments to the server should new search engines be found or likewise.

The search engine is the important part here. Without having a URL, you basically don't have a search result.

I think you are asking for a generic way to search via search engines.

If so, most search engines allow a url parameter after the search endpoint `/search?q=test`.

For example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def perform_search():
    for engine in ['google','bing']:
        url = 'http://' + engine + '.com/search?q=' + request.values.get('q')
        if requests.get(url).status_code == 200:
            return url
        else:
            abort(404, "Search engine not found")


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.debug = True
     app.run("127.0.0.1")
```

This would allow you to construct a URL based on your domain name that this server is running on. If the domain was: `www.mysearch.com` you could hit it with the url: `www.mysearch.com/search?q=MYSEARCHTERM`.

This is a simple answer, with many assumptions as I don't see a way to exactly do what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but the answer relies on a URL so does not address the issue. 
If search?q=MYSEARCHTERM is a defacto standard or actual standard then it could be of possible use in related problems but I think further evidence would be needed.